# compare 3 or more objects

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

Currently, to compare 3 or more integers, We do it this way. `(a < b) && (b < c)`. I know that, `a < b < c` translates to `(a < b) < c` and compares boolean with integer. Is there any way such that, I can overload some operators on a custom Class to achieve continuous comparison? How does languages like python does this?

**Update:** According to accepted answer, I managed to write a [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/CITIZENDOT/8a44af09fa63de675a15af9b152366a0). Have a look.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Comparator {
    bool result;
    T last;

public:
    Comparator(bool _result, T _last) : result(_result), last(_last) {}
    operator bool() const {
        return result;
    }
    Comparator operator<(const T &rhs) const {
        return Comparator(result && (last < rhs), rhs);
    }
    Comparator operator>(const T &rhs) const {
        return Comparator(result && (last > rhs), rhs);
    }
};

class Int {
    int val;

public:
    Int(int _val) : val(_val) {}
    operator int() const {
        return val;
    }
    Comparator<Int> operator<(const Int &rhs) {
        return Comparator<Int>(val < int(rhs), rhs);
    }
    Comparator<Int> operator>(const Int &rhs) {
        return Comparator<Int>(val > int(rhs), rhs);
    }
};

int main() {
    Int a(2), b(3), c(1), d(4), e(6), f(5);
    std::cout << (a < b > c < d < e) << '\n';
    // 2 < 3 > 1 < 4 < 6 > 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can overload `<` for a custom class such that `a < b < c` sort of works, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a < b < c` is *grouped* as `(a < b) < c`.

If `a` or `b` are a type that you define, you could overload `<` for that type to return a *proxy* object, for which an overloaded `<` is also defined. That proxy object would contain the value of `b` along with the result of `a < b`.

It's some hassle, and will not make your code readable either since all C++ programmers know what `a < b < c` should do.

Python has its own syntax and interpreter.